# "Non countable" Series or products

Tags: analysis

Consider $$\sum_{i \in \mathbb R}i$$ Or something like $$\prod_{i\in\mathbb R^*} i$$
Intuitively, one might say in the first case, since every $i$ has an additive inverse, the sum would be $0$. In the second case, similarly, since every $i \in \mathbb R^*$ has a multiplicative inverse, then the product would be 1. ¿Is there any theory regarding this kind of "series" or products? More generaly, one might consider an operation "$\odot$" defined on a family of sets $A_i$ where $i \in I$ and I is non countable, and consider $$\bigodot_{i \in I} A_i $$ 
I'm just asking out of curiosity

Comment: "Uncountable series" fits into the usual Lebesgue integration theory. As for the series in your question, it isn't convergent / doesn't have a well defined value.

Comment: If you search the site for "uncountable sum" (rather than non countable) you'll find a couple of threads about these sorts of things.

Comment: Is a sum over all real numbers significantly different from an integral over the real line?

Comment: @eyeballfrog yes. The involved measures are different.

Comment: Countable sums can be thought about because they are defined in terms of sequences. By what mechanism do you define an uncountable sum?

Comment: Instead of indexing $i$ in $\mathbb N$, we do it on a "larger" set, maybe $\mathbb R$

Comment: It's not just about the indexing, but assigning meaning to the concept of adding up infinitely many things. Normally this is done by using a sequence, which is inherently countable, and taking the limit.

Comment: @AlfredYerger the usual definition for **positive** numbers is the supremum of the sum of countably (or finitely) many numbers and then the usual splitting into positive and negative numbers. That is the same if you integrate with the counting measure.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't taken real analysis (yet), but here is my intuition.

One can make arguments like these, but there is still the problem that these sums and products diverge. For example, even the sum
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \left \lceil{x}\right \rceil $$ diverges, as we can see that the partial sums will alternate between 0 and a high number. Even though we can pair up each terms to get
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}0$$
We cannot say that this sum converges to 0.

Thus I do not believe that we can say what these sums or products are equal to, since they diverge anyways.

Comment: You are right, but the terms in this series are countable (i.e one for each natural number) I was trying to write a sum of a non-countable amount of terms. For example: adding every real number, this cant be expressed as a series from $n$ to $\infty$

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping that this would extend to non-countable numbers, but I see your point. What if we tried the sum
$$\sum_{i \in \mathbb R} (-1)^{\left \lceil{i}\right \rceil} \left \lceil{i}\right \rceil$$
This seems to diverge in the same fashion as my above sum, and yet it can still be argued that it is $0$ by a pairing argument.

Answer (score 0):

There is such a thing as a "Cauchy principal value" of an integral, which, as applied to sums rather than integrals, could be something like $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=-N}^N a_n.$

Notice that if you take $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=-N}^{2N} n,$ you will get a different result from what you get with $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=-N}^N n$, even though both sums have the same set of terms. That sort of thing can happen only if the sum of the positive terms and the sum of the negative terms both diverge to infinity.

Comment: I see, but this is still taking a term for every number in $\mathbb Z$, which is considerably smaller than taking a term for every number in $\mathbb R$